# PC hangs a lot due to physical memory usage

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have 1GB of RAM with 1.50 GHz processor (Intel Atom). My PC is troubling me a lot by hanging; I am not able to do my work for about 5-7 minutes and the level of the physical memory usage history is unstable - it sometimes reaches to the peak, and sometime comes down.

What can be the possible solution to this problem?

Comment: Go to the Crucial website, and allow it to scan your computer - it will show you how much RAM your machine can take and what options you have!

Comment: post a picture of RAMMAp, so that we can see why you have a high memory usage: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx

Comment: No an answer but a possible get-you-started workaround. Check for bloat of all types: manufacturer-installed software, Adobe quick start, other "quick start" programs, basically anything that runs at boot.  Then try to reduce what you deliberately put into the background (chat windows etc.) and open documents particularly large ones. Defragging *might* help the swapping process to happen more quickly. This is rather generic advice, this [PC Advisor article](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/desktop-pc/3502902/how-speed-up-windows/) is slightly more specific.  In the end you need more RAM.

Answer (score 10):

This is called [**thrashing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29), and is common in memory-starved computers.  Once your computer runs out of physical RAM, it must start using storage (e.g. hard disk), which is several orders of magnitude slower than RAM.  This is why the RAM usage is unstable during thrashing, as processes are being shuffled in/out of RAM, to/from the disk.

Preferably you should increase the amount of memory the computer has.  If that's not possible, then make sure you only run the minimum number of processes you can get away with, and avoid running multiple programs simultaneously.

Comment: thanx @breakthrough...for your support but does that means i have to work on this slow computer by waiting everytime..is there any software  to fix this issue or any other tool.

Comment: At this point, you're basically starving the computer for available resources.  There's not much you can do except keep monitoring your memory usage, ensuring that you close any program(s) consuming a lot of memory completely before switching to another application.  Your pagefile should be an adequate size already, as your computer isn't giving you any "out-of-memory" issues, although the fact that the pagefile has to be relied on in this case is why the thrashing occurs.  **Just remember, memory is fairly cheap, and even going from 1GB to 2GB would improve the situation dramatically.**

Comment: okay,thanx i appreciate your help @breakthrough